# How to use browser-sync in a VS project with ntlm

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, browser-sync

I have a asp.net mvc project in which I want to use browser-sync in my gulp file to auto inject css changes and reload the page when I make changes to the site. I've done this before in `proxy` mode, however this site uses windows authentication (NTLM) which can't be proxied as is. Is there a way to make browser-sync work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Browser-Sync has [snippet-mode](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/api/#api-init) for the case in which a proxy won't work. The general usage is to just cut and paste a snippet into the body of your pages and you'll get the injecting/reloading support. However this is a lot of perpetual manual work.

I came up with a convention to eliminate the manual work.

**First** add to your `Web.config`:

```
  <configuration>
      <appSettings>
          <add key="IncludeBrowserSync" value="true" />
          <!--...-->
      </appSettings>
      <!--...-->
  </configuration>
```

**Then** add to your Web.Release.config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="IncludeBrowserSync" value="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
      xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

*This allows us to not worry about accidentally deploying the snippet.*

**Create** in the `Shared` Views folder a `BrowserSync.cshtml`:

```
@using System.Configuration
@if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IncludeBrowserSync"]?.ToLower().Contains("t") ?? false)
{
    <!-- BrowserSync:SNIPPET-->
    <script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">
    //<![CDATA[
        document.write("<script async src='http://HOST:PORT/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname).replace("PORT", parseInt(location.port) + 1));
        //]]>
    </script>
    <!-- BS:BrowserSyncs:END-->
}
```

*As you can see for the snippet, its going to be a little different from what browser sync tells you to cut and paste. The main difference is that it's not going to include the version number (so `npm` can update browser-sync without breaking your snippet) and it's using a convention for the port number to be one above what IISExpress is serving.*

**Now** add `@Html.Partial("BrowserSync")` right above the `</body` in any `_layout.html` you have.

**Finally** to make this all work in your `gulpfile.js` with a `serve` task for browse-sync.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
...
var dllName = "<YourProjectName>.dll";
var iisPort = <YourPortNumber>;

gulp.task('serve', ['default'], function () {

    browserSync.init({
        port: iisPort + 1;
    });

    gulp.watch("<your wildchar to find your editable css files>", ['compile-minimize-css']); 
    /*...*/
    gulp.watch("Views/**/*.cshtml").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("bin/"+dllName).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

*Enjoy automatic refreshes after you start `serve` in the task runner!*

Comment: it is even easier if you are using aspnet 1.0. You can utilize the `<environment>` tags instead of using the webconfig

Answer (score 2):

If you use gulp, you can give [bs-snippet-injector](https://github.com/shakyShane/bs-snippet-injector) a try. It automatically injects the browsersync snippet if you run browsersync with gulp.

```
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

browserSync.use(require("bs-snippet-injector"), {
  // path to the file containing the closing </body> tag
  file: "wwwroot/index.html" 
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  // gupl.watch(...);
  browserSync.init(
    files: 'wwwroot/**'
  );
});
```